# Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined

Tags: javascript, python

Estou tentando rodar um código de pyppeteer (básicamente puppeteer porém para python ao invés de nodejs), e nele rodo um script no navegador inicializado através de .evaluate(), porém algo em meu javascript está suscitando o erro *cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of undefined*.

Estou rodando quatro evals diferentes porque juntá-los não funciona nem mesmo no console do chrome diretamente. Eles são:

```
    await page.evaluate('''function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}''')
    await page.evaluate('''var vari1 = document.querySelector('.swap-wrap');''')
    await page.evaluate('''var divOffset = offset(vari1);''')
    element_coordinates = await page.evaluate('''() => {
        return(divOffset.left, divOffset.top)
        }''')
```

Será que o fato de o código ser assíncrono tem relação com (supostamente) o *el* ser tratado como *undefined*? Se eu executar no console cada um desses comandos contidos no eval um de cada vez, terei o resultado desejado, mas aqui com eval não.

Código na íntegra: https://ideone.com/zddnWR

E o erro na íntegra: https://imgur.com/a/3130PW7

Answer (score 0):

É necessário passar como parâmetro a variável `el` também na primeira expressão do seu código do `page.evaluate(..., el)` para que ela seja diferente de undefined na hora de executar a função **offset**:

```
    el = await page.querySelector(".classe-exemplo")

    await page.evaluate('''function offset(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(),
    scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    console.log(el.getBoundingClientRect().right);
    return { top: rect.top + scrollTop, left: rect.left + scrollLeft }
}''', el)
```

Veja que é necessário definir também antes de realizar o **evaluate** a definição da variável el, **que deverá ser um elemento do documento da página aberto**. No exemplo acima foi utiliza uma query css para buscar um elemento com a classe "classe-exemplo".

Comment: Eu adicionei essa linha em meu código, e agora suscita erro 'offset is not defined' na linha `await page.evaluate('''var divOffset = offset(vari1);''')`